# Convert List to Json in Robot Framework

Tags: python, json, robotframework

after calling specific `Get Regexp Matches` I got following list:

```
['{"result": 1, "error": { "namespace": "global", "reason": "unauthorized" } }']
```

When I am verifying values in following way :

```
Should Be Equal   ${response[0]['result']}  1
Should Be Equal   ${response[0]['error']['namespace']}  global
Should Be Equal   ${response[0]['error']['reason']}  unauthorized
```

Then I got error `Resolving variable '${response[0]['result']}' failed: TypeError: string indices must be integers`
Based on documentation (Robot Frameworks's Collection Library), `Get Regexp Matches` always return list. 
I'd like to verify those values that they matched (result=1, namespace=global, reason=unauthorized) but handling is not working.
Thanks !

Comment: It looks like `response` is a list containing a single string. You should use `resp0 = json.loads(response[0])` and then use `resp0['result']` and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing Json in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053569/parsing-json-in-robot-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @quamrana. Solved in this way:

```
${response} =  Evaluate    json.loads('''${response[0]}''')    json
Should Be Equal   ${response['result']}  1
Should Be Equal   ${response['error']['namespace']}  global
Should Be Equal   ${response['error']['reason']}  unauthorized
```