# Extracting A Value From An Inline JS Script Tag With RobotFramework

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

There is some inline JS that runs at the top our website. It contains some name value pairs that it pulls from the webpage. I am writing tests with robot framework to assert these exist and have values. A small extract of the JS looks as follows:

```
siteId':'1133','offerId':'1228','productId':'549','
```

I am able to assert the existence of the names using the xpath locator as follows

```
page should contain 
element  xpath=/html/head/script[contains(text(),"siteId")]
```

With robot framework and Selenium Library I am asserting that the names exist using the `page should contain element` keyword and this works perfectly.

Now I need to extract the value, so '1133' in the example above.

I have been using the `get element attribute` keyword which has worked well when grabbing values in other places in the DOM. But doesn't seem to work for this case. I keep getting `none` as the value.

My xpath probably needs to written differently for me to be able to extract the value from it, but i'm not sure.

All help or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share complete `script` content not just a *small extract*?

Comment: @JaSON I can't really as its probably 200 lines long. But other than the function at the start of it. Most of it looks like what I have pasted already. It looks to be almost a large JSON file thats getting fired and filled with data from the website. Im just asserting that the names and values exist for a few of them to ensure the script fired and pulled in some values. So all I need to know is the name exists and it has a value. The problem is that the value getting pulled is `none`. So i am thinking my xpath might not be good enough.

Comment: From DOM/XPath point of view `script` element content is just plain text. So, you need text manipulation. Because Selenium uses browsers built-in XPath engines, this leaves only XPath 1.0.- I think it's best to treat that text as javascript or even JSON with proper Python module as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053569/parsing-json-in-robot-framework

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the contents of the script tag by fetching the value of the `innerHTML` attribute. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#:%7E:text=Setting%20the%20value%20of%20innerHTML%20lets%20you%20easily%20replace%20the,document.)

I am not familiar with robot framework, but based on the info you provided, I suspect using `get element attribute` with `innerHTML` will return the script tag's contents as a String, which you could then match using a regular expression.