# Store the response value in a variable in ROBOT Framework

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I got the below response from a POST request and want to store the TOKEN value in an variable and use it for future use.

{"AccountName":"tester-01","**token**":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCFtZSI6InN2Yy1kb2NwLXRlc3Rlcjkj5eWSZOSAExHVDL6V9_qgVOJ3pA","refreshvalue":"5X6g8QZ3rk1RWQXLdItXlKnfwTPGjQ==","validFrom":"2021-09-16T05:45:44Z","validTo":"2021-09-16T06:45:44Z","
refreshValidTo":"2021-09-16T11:45:44Z"}

The code snippet for the above response is

```
   ${body}=  create dictionary       username=test12345    password=12345

   ${header}=    create dictionary       Content-Type=application/json

  ${login}=  post on session  docp  /login  json=${body}    headers=${header}

   ${value}=      Set Variable    ${login['token']}
```

When I try to set the response in the value variable I get the below error.

```
Resolving variable '${login['token']}' failed: TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable.
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing Json in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053569/parsing-json-in-robot-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you issue a request the returned data - the `login` variable in your case - is a response object, not just the payload. It contains as properties the headers, payload, the request that was sent, and a lot others; [see the library documentation, where it is described in details](https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html#Response%20Object).

You're targeting the payload/the content of the respone; as you're dealing with a json api and expect it to be such, there is a convenience method that will return you that, parsed as a python dictionary:

```
${login}=  post on session  docp  /login  json=${body}    headers=${header}
${payload}=    Set Variable    ${login.json()}    # this will be the data you got from the service, as a plain dictionary 
${value}=      Set Variable    ${payload['token']}
```

Comment: Executed the above snippet and got the below error

failed: TypeError: Expression must be string, got dictionary.

It was able to generate the token and all but guess the payload variable failed

Comment: Change `Evaluate` to `Set Variable` when setting `payload`

Comment: What if I want to save the variable in another file say xyz.env and use it for other operations ?

Comment: Then have a look at the OperatingSystem library https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html

Comment: This answer lets me retrieve a POST image id that I needed. Thanks!